# How to disable radio button when Commerce Stock = 0?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, commerce

I'm using Commerce Kickstart and I have a term reference for Size, and I'm using the Check boxes/radio buttons widget with Commerce Stock and Commerce fancy attributes.

Currently, when the stock of number of a product is 0, the "Add to cart" button is disabled. I would like to take this further by disabling the radio button so that the user can see that a product is out of stock before clicking "Add to cart".

I've tried disabling the product when its stock reaches 0 here: [Disable product when out of stock](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33994/disable-product-when-out-of-stock?rq=1) but then the radio button just doesn't get printed when the product is disabled (ie. only printing S,L and XL when M is out of stock) I would still like to print the radio button option for "M" but as a disabled button.

How may I achieve this? Thanks!