# Unpublish commerce product display when stock is '0' with rules

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

I tried it with the reaction *after saving commerce product* but I wasn't able to access the node.

I also tried accessing the node by looping through `product_reference` field and used *set a data value* and selected `list-item:status` and then `unpublished`, but I got this message:

> Unable to modify data "list-item:status": Entity property
>   field_product_reference_node doesn't support writing.

and

> Unable to evaluate action data_set.

in the error logs.

Comment: This looks like it may be a duplicate of: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33994/disable-product-when-out-of-stock

Comment: It's not the same. That post is about product, mine is about product display.